# connect 4 namespace through ovs bridge

Tags: virtual-machine, bridge, namespace

I would like to ask how can I connect 4 namespaces to one ovs brdige , they all a re in one host . 
I tried 2 pairs of veth for these 4 namespaces and add internal port to the bridge , but the namespace can be pinged only from another end of veth .

```
[root@centos7 ~]# ovs-vsctl show
689941bc-760e-451e-a91c-ddc33caf2396
Bridge brtest
    Port "test1"
        tag: 9
        Interface "test1"
            type: internal
    Port "test4"
        tag: 9
        Interface "test4"
            type: internal
    Port "test2"
        tag: 9
        Interface "test2"
            type: internal
    Port brtest
        Interface brtest
            type: internal
    Port "test3"
        tag: 9
        Interface "test3"
            type: internal
ovs_version: "2.7.0"

ip netns exec nstest1 ifconfig test1 promisc
ip netns exec nstest2 ifconfig test2 promisc
ip netns exec nstest3 ifconfig test3 promisc
ip netns exec nstest4 ifconfig test4 promisc
```

I have turned on the promisc of veth of namespace , and assign ip from 172.24.0.11 to 172.24.0.14 respectively . But only nstest1 can get through to nstest2 and nstest3 to nstest4 , because nstest1 and nstest2 connected by a pair of veth and nstest3 and nstest4 connected by another paire of veth .

Can I get them totally through for these 4 namespace ?

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer , just create veth pair for these 4 namespaces , and one end assign to the namespace and the other one add to the virtual bridge as a port . Then these 4 namespaces can be through from any one of them

```
ip link set test1a netns nstest1
ip link set test2a netns nstest2
ip link set test3a netns nstest3
ip link set test4a netns nstest4
ovs-vsctl br-list
ovs-vsctl list-br
ovs-vsctl show
ovs-vsctl add-br br0
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 test1b
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 test2b
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 test3b
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 test4b
ip netns exec nstest1 ifconfig test1a 172.24.0.11/24 promisc up
ip netns exec nstest2 ifconfig test2a 172.24.0.12/24 promisc up
ip netns exec nstest3 ifconfig test3a 172.24.0.13/24 promisc up
ip netns exec nstest4 ifconfig test4a 172.24.0.14/24 promisc up

ip link set dev test2b up
ip link set dev test1b up
ip link set dev test3b up
ip link set dev test4b up
```